# How to prevent VPN toggle switch access on iPhone\iPad – For Enterprise Devices

Tags: vpn, enterprise, mdm

I would like to create iOS device configuration profile, which should force user to access VPN, I was able to create configuration profile  successfully and was able to send all device traffic via VPN(by selecting ‘Send All Traffic’ check box), but on device still user see option to On/Off switch for VPN, in other word they are able to turn off VPN, my ‘Send All Traffic via VPN’ setting works only if on device user turn on VPN toggle switch.

I would like to disable VPN toggle button switch, so after installation of Device configuration profile, user should not able to turn off VPN, Any suggestion\input exactly what I should write in .mobileconfig file so device disable ‘VPN toggle’ switch.

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that there's a new feature in iOS 8 called "Always-on VPN"

Excerpt from here https://www.apple.com/br/privacy/docs/iOS_Security_Guide_Oct_2014.pdf

> iOS 8 introduces Always-on VPN, which can be configured for devices managed via
>   MDM and supervised using Apple Configurator or the Device Enrollment Program. This
>   eliminates the need for users to turn on VPN to enable protection when connecting to
>   Wi-Fi networks. Always-on VPN gives an organization full control over device traffic by
>   tunneling all IP traffic back to the organization. The default tunneling protocol, IKEv2,
>   secures traffic transmission with data encryption. The organization can now monitor and
>   filter traffic to and from its devices, secure data within its network, and restrict device
>   access to the Internet

Please be aware that there is a difference between device regarded as managed (actually apps and settings are managed) and devices regarded as supervised. You supervise a device on initial registration, something you want to do only for corporate owned devices, not BYOD.

Cheers
Jens

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration profile with a restriction which will prevent a user from turning VPN off.

The closest you can get is to configure "Enable VPN on Demand". This way, if some applications try to access any hosts which match iOS will turn VPN automatically.

Look at this page: http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/On_Demand_VPN_Explained